# Invalid testPattern --config=jest.config.js with react-scripts with Mono Repo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to set a custom jest.config to react-scripts via:

`"test": "react-scripts test -- --config=jest.config.js",`

I feel it is important to mention that I have a mono repo.

However this has created the following error:

```
Invalid testPattern --config=jest.config.js|--watch|--config|{"roots":["<rootDir>/src"],"collectCoverageFrom":["src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","!src/**/*.d.ts"],"setupFiles":["/var/www/tractable/property-estimating/node_modules/react-app-polyfill/jsdom.js"],"setupFilesAfterEnv":["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"],"testMatch":["<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],"testEnvironment":"jsdom","testRunner":"/var/www/tractable/property-estimating/node_modules/jest-circus/runner.js","transform":{"^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$":"/var/www/tractable/property-estimating/node_modules/react-scripts/config/jest/babelTransform.js","^.+\\.css$":"/var/www/tractable/property-estimating/node_modules/react-scripts/config/jest/cssTransform.js","^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)":"/var/www/tractable/property-estimating/node_modules/react-scripts/config/jest/fileTransform.js"},"transformIgnorePatterns":["[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$","^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"],"modulePaths":["/var/www/tractable/property-estimating/frontend/claim-handler/src"],"moduleNameMapper":{"^react-native$":"react-native-web","^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$":"identity-obj-proxy"},"moduleFileExtensions":["web.js","js","web.ts","ts","web.tsx","tsx","json","web.jsx","jsx","node"],"watchPlugins":["jest-watch-typeahead/filename","jest-watch-typeahead/testname"],"resetMocks":true,"rootDir":"/var/www/tractable/property-estimating/frontend/claim-handler"}|--env|/var/www/tractable/property-estimating/node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js supplied. Running all tests instead.
```

Versions

```
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue. Replaced script as follows

```
"test": "react-scripts test -- --config=jest.config.js",
```

with

```
"test": "jest",
```

As react-scripts already have jest inside. No need to install it explicitly.

Answer (score -5):

Did you try: `"test": "react-scripts test --config=jest.config.js"`?

This might work

Comment: This would not work, as it passes it directly to jest, rather than an option. Thank you for trying to help

Comment: Please provide more context, how it can be useful, or any links that might help OP.

Comment: Okay. I referred to this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#disabling-jsdom. Here `env` is passed directly instead of an extra `--`.